# Javascript - Console.log does not log correctly

Tags: javascript, console

In console, of any web page, I do:

`console.log(11111111111111111);`

The result is:
`11111111111111112`

So I am really confused, trying to add 1s and see what happens:

- `111111111111111111` -> `111111111111111100`
- `1111111111111111111` -> `1111111111111111200`
- `11111111111111111111` -> `11111111111111110000`
- `111111111111111111111` -> `111111111111111110000`

Am I going crazy?
What causes this to happen?

Is this intended? Is this a bug with Javascript?

[image]

*Note:* I am pretty sure it is not an integer overflow or something, because adding one `1` more goes to `1.1111111111111111e+21` which is correct.

---

This question differs from [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/307179/what-is-javascripts-highest-integer-value-that-a-number-can-go-to-without-losin), because I am not asking about the limit of numbers that can be represented accurately, I am asking more like:

Why `11111111111111111` -> `11111111111111112` instead of `11111111111111111` -> `1.1111111111111111e+16` (scientific notation)

Comment: It's because the number is too big and it becomes too big to represent accurately thus the discrepancy.

Comment: @AndrewLi I understand it loses accuracy, but why does it at all do that? why show an incorrect thing instead of a correct number in other notation?